# How to interpret XRD results?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, stress-strain, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I am given several datapoints of XRD strain information. It comes from XRD measurement of a thin layer (100 nm) of semiconductor deposited on top of another semiconductor.

The result I'm given is called "strain". But as I know from literature, there is no such thing as just strain. There are several strains in various directions, e.g.:

[image]

Where xx and yy denote "along the interface" direction, and zz denote "away from interface" direction.

So when I'm given just "Strain" info from XRD, which is it?

Wikipedia gives the explanation based on the following picture:
[image]

So I would guess we measure d, which corresponds to $\epsilon_{zz}$.

I guess that having $C_{11}$ and $C_{12}$ from the literature one might calculate any strain you want, but in practice... which strain is actually measured?

Comment: You can get both in-plane and out-of-plane strain depending on what peaks you look at with which scattering conditions.

Comment: @JonCuster thank you, it is quite eye-opening!